# Excel is giving Non-optimal solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, performance

I am performing a basic cost minimization for a transport problem, however, Excel's solver (LP Simplex) is giving me a solution that is almost twice as high as an alternate solution that I found for the problem. Is there any explanation as to why Simplex is not giving the global minimum?
Here is the file, on the left is the result from Solver and the right has the manually entered result
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MdYffQNuyfRtKX8p6l_X6iZKOTg0Prjw

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas are not referring to the same data.

In particular, `F8:F10 <> N8:N10`

and that last column is fixed as it is not in the range of columns being changed by Solver.

If you adjust `F8:F10` so that it is the same as `N8:N10` you will get the same solution in Solver as with your manual entry.